# Show triangular inequality in metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X,\rho)$ be a metric space. I want to show that the function

$\sigma(x,y)=\min\{1,\rho(x,y)\}$ is a metric on the set $X$. I

It is fairly straightforward to show that

$(*)$ $\sigma(x,y)\geq0$  for every $x,y\in X$

$(*)$ $\sigma(x,y)=0$ iff $x=y$

$(*)$ $\sigma(x,y)=\sigma(y,x)$ for every $x,y\in X$

However, I was stuck while trying to show that

$\sigma(x,y)\leq \sigma(x,z)+\sigma(z,y)$  for every $x,y,z \in X$.

Please help me in showing this triangle inequality.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider the case when $\rho(x,z)$ or $\rho(z,y)$ are greater than or equal to 1. Then suppose otherwise.

Comment: Can you say much more @JessicaK I couldn't use this comment

Comment: If either $\rho(x,z)$ or $\rho(z,y)\geq 1$. What does this say about the relationship between $\sigma(x,y)$ and $\sigma(x,z) + \sigma(z,y)$?

Answer (score 1):

Following @JessicaK's comment, we differentiate the cases $\rho(x,z), \rho(z,y) \gtreqless 1$.

If both $\rho(x,z), \rho(z,y) \le 1$, we have $\sigma(x,z) = \rho(x,z)$, $\sigma(z,y) = \rho(z,y)$, hence
\begin{align*}
  \sigma(x,y) &\le \rho(x,y)\\
              & \le \rho(x,z) + \rho(z,y) & \text{Triangle inequality for $\rho$}\\
              &= \sigma(x,z) + \sigma(z,y)
\end{align*}
If $\rho(x,z) > 1$ or $\rho(z,y) > 1$, then $\sigma(x,z) = 1$ or $\sigma(z,y) = 1$, hence $\sigma(x,z) + \sigma(z,y) \ge 1$, hence
\begin{align*}
  \sigma(x,y) &\le 1\\
              &\le \sigma(x,z) + \sigma(z,y).
\end{align*}